# Rendering JSX from function in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm pretty new to Vue.Js and I'm trying to figure out how to render JSX from a function within a Vue.JS Template. I tried to follow a similar syntax to React; however, that appears to be wrong. I have read something about using slots but I'm not sure how that would work. Thanks.

```
<template>
  <div id="dashboard">
                  {{ this.renderChart(expandTable) }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Dashboard',
    components: {
    },
    data () {
      return {
        expandTable: false,
        symbolsData: [],
        symbolsFilter: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      renderChart (expanded) {
        if(!expanded) {
            return ( //JSX I'm trying to render
              <b-col cols="12">
                <chart-widget selectedSymbol={selectedSymbol}></chart-widget>
              </b-col>
            )
          } else {
            return (
              <b-col cols="8">
                <chart-widget :selectedSymbol="selectedSymbol"></chart-widget>
              </b-col>
            )
          }
        }
      }

    },
...
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use both a template and JSX. They are two alternatives for [how to generate a render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX).

For your example here, you should probably use [`v-if` and `v-else`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) in your template, around the HTML block alternatives.